# Is it possible to sort history by favicon in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, history, favicon

In Firefox 15.0.1 (for Windows desktop), is it possible to sort history by favicon?

Comment: I always add the site name while saving to Favorites, so something like "SU - " or "\[SU] " in front of every link from this site groups all of them together.

Comment: Then why not Show All History and sort by the Location column? Isn't that what you want to achieve? (Sorting by favicon implies to me you actually want to sort by site.)

Comment: How does one sort by an image in the first place? Do you mean *group by* favicon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the **Show All History** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) window and sort by the Location column.

Even if group by favicon were to be available, unfortunately not all sites have favicons, and I've also seen some with the same favicon being used, which would certainly mess up the sorting.